# JQuery: what's the difference between these two $.get() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

**Server:**

```
def csv_data(request): #mapped to url /csv_data
    with open('my_static_data.csv', 'r') as csv:
        response = HttpResponse(csv.read(), content_type="text/csv")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.csv"'
    return response #returns the csv file
```

**Client:**

1.

```
function csv_data() {
  var response = $.get('/csv_data');
  return response;
}

$(function () {
  var my_data = csv_data();
  console.log(my_data); //returns a response object
  console.log(my_data.responseText); //undefined?!
}
```

2.

```
$(function () {
  $.get('/csv_data', function(d) {
    console.log(d); // returns csv_data. Why not the same response object?
  });
}
```

The data returned by Method #2 is what I intended to use. Why is my_data.responseText is `undefined`, and why do these two methods return different objects?

Comment: I think it has to do something with the time it takes to retrieve the data from the get request, but I would like someone explain what exactly is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` is not an overloaded jQuery function; it just returns [the *asynchronous* request object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) back for convenience, and although that object exists, its response has not yet been filled. You still need to use a callback to use the result:

```
function csv_data(callback) {
  $.get('/csv_data', callback);
}

$(function () {
  csv_data(function(my_data) {
    console.log(my_data); // returns a response object
    console.log(my_data.responseText); // not undefined
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First one returns a deferred object.

```
function csv_data() {
   return $.get('/csv_data');
}

csv_data().done(function(my_data) {
    console.log(my_data);
});
```

Just a different way of managing the callback.

So no matter what, the data is accessed via the callback. Just that in the first example, you can assign it via the returned object, and in the second, it's assigned as an argument to `$.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the  XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information).

So `response` in this code, is not the actual data from the AJAX request:

```
var response = $.get('/csv_data');
```

Whereas, here, `d` is the data response from the AJAX request:

```
$(function () {
  $.get('/csv_data', function(d) {
    console.log(d); // returns csv_data. Why not the same response object?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the requests are async by default. In the first case you want to use the result right after the request started.
In the second one, you define a callback which is only called after the request is finished.